# Xamarin Forms Android Transparent ViewCell

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have one Problem. 
I created new ViewCellRenderer for Android.
If I put color "Transparent", SelectedItem gets Orange Color. 
Other colors work without problems. 
Does anyone have any solution ?

Xamarin.Forms. I'm testing on Android

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line to your styles.xml inside resource folder of android project

```
 <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">#D3D3D3</item>
```

you can change the selected color of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.

You can try this. Create an CustomViewCell class in Xamarin.Portable Project

public class ExtendedViewCell : ViewCell
   {
       public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedBackgroundColorProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create("SelectedBackgroundColor",
                                   typeof(Color),
                                   typeof(ExtendedViewCell),
                                   Color.Default);

```
   public Color SelectedBackgroundColor
   {
       get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedBackgroundColorProperty); }
       set { SetValue(SelectedBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
   }
```

}

After Creating the CustomViewCell, Create Custom Renderer for Android and ios.
Android Rednerer===========

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedViewCell), typeof(ExtendedViewCellRenderer))]
namespace ProjectName.Droid.Renderers
{
   public class ExtendedViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
   {

```
   private Android.Views.View _cellCore;
   private Drawable _unselectedBackground;
   private bool _selected;

   protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item,
                                                     Android.Views.View convertView,
                                                     ViewGroup parent,
                                                     Context context)
   {
       _cellCore = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);

       _selected = false;
       _unselectedBackground = _cellCore.Background;

       return _cellCore;
   }

   protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   {
       base.OnCellPropertyChanged(sender, args);

       if (args.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
       {
           _selected = !_selected;

           if (_selected)
           {
               var extendedViewCell = sender as ExtendedViewCell;
               _cellCore.SetBackgroundColor(extendedViewCell.SelectedBackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
           }
           else
           {
               _cellCore.SetBackground(_unselectedBackground);
           }
       }
   }
```

}
}

iOS Renderer==============

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedViewCell), typeof(ExtendedViewCellRenderer))]
namespace ProjectName.iOS.Renderer
{
   public class ExtendedViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
   {
       public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
       {
           var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
           var view = item as ExtendedViewCell;

```
       cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView
       {
           BackgroundColor = view.SelectedBackgroundColor.ToUIColor()
       };

       return cell;
   }
```

}
}

Change ViewCell to CustomView Cell.
XAML=========

This code Works for me.